# How do I reverse lookup on an ansible dict?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there a way to transform a dict into another dict in order to invert the lookup based on an internal field?  I expect the internal field to be unique for each item, and always present.  Here's an example of what I want to do.

I have a data structure as such:

```
lookup_dict:
  a1:
    b: 123
  a2:
    b: 456
  a3:
    b: 789
```

The mapping between `a` and `b` is 1-to-1 and onto.  I want to convert it to:

```
reverse_lookup_dict:
  123: a1
  456: a2
  789: a3
```

So I can then perform reverse lookup for a using b.

Comment: i was trying to meet your requirements by using in a loop the `set_fact` module to add key:value pairs to the `converted_stuff` var. but on each iteration it overwrites the variable completely, so the previous key/value pairs are lost. is getting the `converted_stuff` as a list of a single key/value pair an option for you?

Comment: I am provided something with the structure in `stuff`, but I need to perform lookups of `item_id` at a later points based on `external_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some study, I found the answer to be the following:

```
name: Reverse Lookup
set_fact:
  reverse_lookup_dict: "{{reverse_lookup_dict|default({})|combine({item.value.b: item.key})}}"
loop: "{{lookup('dict', lookup_dict)}}"
```

Comment: it should be `item.value.external_id`, thanks for sharing the solution

Answer (score 3):

You can do this just by using vars and `dict2items` + `items2dict`:

Here's an examples mapping called `forward` (that maps a silly string to an ID) that is built from the reverse map, named `reverse`:

```
reverse:
  0x0019: staff
  0x011a: visitors
  0x3bbe: executives
  0xf9c4: vpn

forward: >-
  {{ reverse 
   | dict2items 
   | items2dict(key_name="value", value_name="key" }}
```

Comment: I like this; it's cleaner than mine.  The use case is slightly different, in that in my "forward", the value itself is a dict, and one of the values of *that* dict would be the key in the "reverse".